# On PrimeFaces tab view

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
    public class Tabs {
        public Tabs() {
            fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            tabView = (TabView) fc.getApplication().createComponent(
                    "org.primefaces.component.TabView");
            Tab tab1 = new Tab();
            tab1.setTitle("Default tab");
                    Tab tab2 = new Tab();
            tab2.setTitle("Manage Favorites");
            tab2.setClosable(true);
            tabView.getChildren().add(tab1);
            tabView.getChildren().add(tab2);

            tabView.setActiveIndex(0);
        }

    public TabView getTabView() {
        return tabView;
    }

    public void setTabView(TabView tabView) {
        this.tabView = tabView;
    }

    public void addTabs() {
        Tab tab3 = new Tab();
        tab3.setTitle("Manage Favorites");
        tab3.setClosable(true);
        tabView.getChildren().add(tab3);
        System.out.println("Called");
    }

    FacesContext fc;
    TabView tabView;
}
```

Here is the bean from which we're adding the tabs in the tabview . Works perfectly fine ..

```
<p:tabView id="mytabview" orientation="left" binding="#{Tabs.tabView}"
            style="position:relative" rendered="true" styleClass="tabs">
        </p:tabView>
```

This does show the tab but its completely empty . I want to add a panel grid in these tabs .

Problem is: How do I add a panelgrid at the programming end so that the tab view display some information.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it easier if you just define the tabs you will use inside `<p:tabView>` tag?

Example:

```
<p:tab id="tab1" title="Godfather Part I">  
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="10">  
        <h:outputText id="tab1Text"  
            value="The story begins as Don Vito Corleone, the head of a New York Mafia family, oversees his daughter's wedding.  
            His beloved son Michael has just come home from the war, but does not intend to become part of his father's business. T  
            hrough Michael's life the nature of the family business becomes clear. The business of the family is just like the head of the family, kind and benevolent to those who give respect,  
            but given to ruthless violence whenever anything stands against the good of the family." />  
    </h:panelGrid>  
</p:tab>  

<p:tab id="tab2" title="Godfather Part II">  
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="10">   
        <h:outputText id="tab2Text" value="Francis Ford Coppola's legendary continuation and sequel to his landmark 1972 film, The_Godfather, parallels the young Vito Corleone's rise with his son Michael's spiritual fall, deepening The_Godfather's depiction of the dark side of the American dream.  
        In the early 1900s, the child Vito flees his Sicilian village for America after the local Mafia kills his family. Vito struggles to make a living, legally or illegally, for his wife and growing brood in Little Italy,  
        killing the local Black Hand Fanucci after he demands his customary cut of the tyro's business. With Fanucci gone, Vito's communal stature grows."/>  
    </h:panelGrid>  
</p:tab>
```

Defining the tabs in your jsf page will be easier, because you gonna define it right in the page, and not calling it by methods. Calling it by methods would be useful only if you need more refined implementations that would change the behavior of the component at all.

I got this example from here: http://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tabview.jsf

Good luck!